# Hiding one table row when another row is empty

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have some data in a table and I dynamically generate two different kinds of rows. The first kind is a date row and the second is a content row. This way I can display e.g. the correct news below the date row corresponding to this.

```
<table class="channel-data">
<tbody>
    <?php 
    $current_date = "";
    while($programs=$obj->fetchNextObject($sql_tv_programs)):?>


    <?php if($current_date != $programs->date):?>
    <tr class="date active" id="date_<?php echo $programs->date?>">  
        <td>
            <?php 
                $current_date = $programs->date;

                $day = date('l', strtotime($current_date));
                $day_num = date('j', strtotime($current_date));
                $month = date('M', strtotime($current_date));
            ?>

            <div  class="current" style="display: block;">
                <h2>
                    <span id="match-day" class="tv_date"><span class="match-month-date"><span class="match-month"><?php echo translate($month) ?></span><span class="match-date"><?php echo date('d', strtotime($programs->end))?></span></span><?php echo translate($day) ?></span>
                </h2>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif ?>
        <tr class="row sport_<?php echo $programs->sport_id?> active" onclick="$(this).siblings().children().children('.content').slideUp(200);$(this).children().children('.content').slideToggle(200);">
    <td>


                <div class="m">
                <p>bla</p>
                </div>
                <div class="i">
        <img src="#">
                </div>
                <div class="t">
                </div>
                <div class="l">
                </div>
                <div class="v">

                </div>
                <div class="content">

                    <div class="tv_league_responsive">
                    <span>&nbsp;<?php echo $programs->league?></span>
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="ts-calendar"><a>some</a></li>
                        <li class="ts-facebook"><a>thing</a></li>
                        <li class="ts-twitter"><a>new</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php
    endif;
    endwhile
    ?>
</tbody>
```

I have simplified my code in order to make it easier to understand. The real question is regarding my jquery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('table.channel-data .row').hasClass('active')) {
        $('#date_<?php echo $programs->date?>').addClass('hello');
    }
});
```

Here I try to add a class to a specific generated id if a row ha the class 'active'. This does not work, however. What would be a better way of doing this? My goal is to be able to hide the date row whenever there is no corresponding entries of the .row class. Hope this isn't too badly formulated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try :-**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var td = $('table.channel-data tr td:eq(1)');
   var tdHtml = td.html();
   setInterval(function() {
      //empty row
      if (td.html() =="") {
         // it has changed
         td.hide();
      }
   }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want, if you just want to add the class to the same element you can just use $(this) selector without checking its id

```
    //--like this---
    if($('table.channel-data .row').hasClass('active')) {
         $(this).addClass('hello');
    }
```

Hope it helps!
Cheers,
Ajju